# Sitecore Logging default behavior in Azure app insight

Tags: sitecore-client, azure, logging

I need to check the publishing sitecore logs in azure app insight.
I tried go to Transaction search of app insight and search for publish then I'm able to see publish items with no details that who published and looks like that are azure logs not sitecore.

[image]

Is there any default behavior to see sitecore logs in azure app insight and if not how we can see them.
Your response is really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to filter by Logger Name `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Publishing`or Category `Publishing`. If this does not give you any more insights, check on your publishing instance what logging level you have for `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Publishing` logger. Easiest way to see this is to go to `publishingInstance.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and then search for given logger i.e.

```
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Publishing" additivity="false" patch:source="z.EnvironmentSettings.config">
  <level value="Warn"/>
  <appender-ref ref="PublishingLogFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AzureFallbackAppender" desc="AzureFallbackAppender" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceContentManagement.Administration.config"/>
</logger>
```

As you can see log level in given example is set to "Warning". This can be set to Debug, Info, Warn, Error.

Comment: I'm able to see.
Thanks @Kamil